# Consider or consider as

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can I use "consider as' in the meaning "think about options to be/do someone/something?"
For example, "If you have a fashion brand and consider this company as your partner, think about the options for cooperation" (here, I say that this is only one of the options: it may be this company, and may be the other one)

Comment: It's a stylistic choice whether to include ***as*** (or the alternative ***to be***) in your cited context. Personally, I would use ***to be*** with ***consider*** (or, say, ***expect***), but I'd use ***as*** with ***treat*** or ***recognise***. But that's *my* stylistic choice; others may see it differently.

Answer (score 1):

"Consider for (some position or role)" is better if you are thinking about whether to hire, engage, or contract with someone. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consider) has the example "We are considering you for the job."

"Consider as" in contrast is used where someone does not formally hold a status/role/characteristic but is viewed as if they were in that status/role/characteristic: "We consider them as our partner" means they're not actually our partner, but the relationship is so close that it is as good as being partners.

If you just want to express your thoughts more generally, you can use "consider" without a preposition, e.g. you might say "I don't consider him a good employee" or "I consider him my closest friend".

However, these rules are probably not applied 100%, as there is a lot of freedom about English preposition use.